# trying to set up ssl cert but after a2ensite apache refuse to start

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

As title said, Im on a ubuntu 16.04 fresh installed system,

I run sudo service apache2 status, it shows:

```
Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-10-26 15:11:36 PDT; 3s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 3891 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 3873 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 3821 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 26 15:10:50 12345server3 apache2[3821]:  * Starting Apache 
httpd web server apache2
Oct 26 15:10:50 12345server3 apache2[3821]: AH00558: apache2: 
Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, 
using 127.0.1.1. Set 
Oct 26 15:10:51 12345server3 apache2[3821]:  *
Oct 26 15:10:51 12345server3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web 
server.
Oct 26 15:11:36 12345server3 systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 
web server.
Oct 26 15:11:36 12345server3 apache2[3873]:  * Reloading Apache 
httpd web server apache2
Oct 26 15:11:36 12345server3 apache2[3873]:  *
Oct 26 15:11:36 12345server3 systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Apache2 web 
server.
Oct 26 15:11:36 12345server3 apache2[3891]:  * Stopping Apache 
httpd web server apache2
Oct 26 15:11:36 12345server3 apache2[3891]:  *
```

My vhost config looks like:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName fdsfdsdsa.com
    ServerAlias www.fdsfdsdsa.com
ServerAdmin gffddd@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com



ErrorLog /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com/logs/access.log combined



    <Directory /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/fdsfdsdsa.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/fdsfdsdsa.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/2.crt

ServerAdmin tyfyfhj@gmail.com
ServerName fdsfdsdsa.com
ServerAlias fdsfdsdsa.com #If using alternate names for a host
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com
ErrorLog /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com/logs/errorssl.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com/logs/accessssl.log combined
<Directory /var/www/html/fdsfdsdsa.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I can not come up with an idea where the problem is, 
I freshly made the cert put them in the right folder,
and as long as i a2ensite this ssl site the apache2 immediately shutdown

the error log shows:
'AH00016: Configuration Failed'
only this

if I disable the ssl site, other sites works flawlessly

Anyone could help or come up with ideas were apprecoiated.

Comment: Is the Apache ssl module enabled? sudo a2enmod ssl

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably an issue with your SSL certificate files. Can you verify them with this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/ssl/ssl_faq.html#verify

Comment: $ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt | openssl md5
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key | openssl md5 After I run these two command it gives me two different md5, so this is cert problem?